# Change dest folder for gulp

Tags: gulp, nunjucks

I'm using the plugin `gulp-nunjucks-render` with gulp as following:

```
gulp.task("nunjucks", () => {
  return gulp
    .src(src_folder + "pages/**/*.njk", {
      base: src_folder,
      since: gulp.lastRun("nunjucks"),
    })
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(
      data(() =>
        JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(src_folder + "datas/dist/data.json"))
      )
    )
    .pipe(nunjucks())
    .pipe(beautify.html({ indent_size: 2 }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_folder))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

I want the generated html files to be inside the `dist_folder` and not inside `dist_folder` + "pages".

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need `.pipe(dest('dist_folder'))` appending as per these docs: https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/dest/

```
gulp.task("nunjucks", () => {
  return gulp
    .src(src_folder + "pages/**/*.njk", {
      base: src_folder,
      since: gulp.lastRun("nunjucks"),
    })
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(
      data(() =>
        JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(src_folder + "datas/dist/data.json"))
      )
    )
    .pipe(nunjucks())
    .pipe(beautify.html({ indent_size: 2 }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_folder))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    .pipe(dest('dist_folder'));
});
```

Comment: I already used '.pipe(gulp.dest(dist_folder))'

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the `pages` directory so as mentioned here [glob-base](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts/#glob-base), `pages` needs to be part of your `base`:

> A glob `base` - sometimes called glob parent - is the path segment
> before any special characters in a glob string. As such, the glob `base`
> of `/src/js/**.js` is `/src/js/`.

> Vinyl instances generated by `src()` are constructed with the glob `base`
> set as their `base` property. When written to the file system with
> `dest()`, the `base` will be removed from the output path to preserve
> directory structures.

It is naturally part of your `base` (it is before the globstar `**` in your `src`) so if you remove the `base` property that you added you will get the behaviour you wanted since

**"When written to the file system with
dest(), the `base` will be removed from the output path"**.

Gulp will automatically set the base to `src_folder + "pages"` if you remove the `base` option that you set.

---

Alternatively, if you do want to specifically set the `base` property you could use this:

```js
  return gulp
    .src(src_folder + "pages/**/*.njk", {
      base: src_folder  + "pages",
      since: gulp.lastRun("nunjucks"),
    })
...
```

which in your specific case does exactly the same thing as not setting the `base` property at all!